# Whats the right way to manipulate a model instance in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

So I have a React component that accepts an instance of a function constructor (a `Car`).

The component's job is to display information about the `Car` and manipulate it based on the `Car`'s public interface (methods and properties).

In the example below, a child component should add an accident on button click.

Question: What is the right way for the child to manipulate properties of the `Car` instance? The root parent's state stores reference to the instance of the `Car`, and the children are able to manipulate the `Car`'s properties (like `.accidents`), but see the various `onChange` examples for why I'm struggling to find the right React way to do this.

I'd like to avoid a heavy handed solution like Flux to store this state.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

```
function Car(name, color) {
  this.name = name;
  this.color = color;
  this.accidents = [];
}

const myCar = new Car('Ferrari', 'Red');
myCar.accidents.push('accident #1');


class Accident extends React.Component {
  handleButton1 = () => {
    const newAccident = 'accident type1 # ' + Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
    this.props.onChange1(newAccident);
  }

  handleButton2 = () => {
    const newAccident = 'accident type2 # ' + Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
    this.props.onChange2(newAccident);
  }

  handleButton3 = () => {
    const newAccident = 'accident type3 # ' + Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
    this.props.accidents.push(newAccident);
    this.props.onChange3();
  }

  handleButton4 = () => {
    const newAccident = 'accident type4 # ' + Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
    this.props.accidents.push(newAccident);
    // This circumvents React's state management, so the parent doesnt
    // rerender when its state changes.
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleButton1}>
          Add accident (onChange1)
        </button>
        <button onClick={this.handleButton2}>
          Add accident (onChange2)
        </button>
        <button onClick={this.handleButton3}>
          Add accident (onChange3)
        </button>
        <button onClick={this.handleButton4}>
          Add accident (option 4)
        </button>
        <ul>
          {this.props.accidents.map((a, i) => <li key={i}>{a}</li>)}
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class DisplayCard extends React.Component {
  state = {
    editingCar: this.props.car
  }

  // Push the new accident into state and set it with the same reference.
  onChange1 = (newAccident) => {
    this.state.editingCar.accidents.push(newAccident);
    // Is this semantically different than calling this.forceUpdate?
    this.setState({
      editingCar: this.state.editingCar,
    });
  }

  // Clone the existing state we want to update and explicitly set that new state
  onChange2 = (newAccident) => {
    const newAccidentList = _.cloneDeep(this.state.editingCar.accidents);
    newAccidentList.push(newAccident);

    // Setting our new accident list like this converts editingCar to a POJO
    // editingCar.name is lost because a deep merge does not happen.
    this.setState({
      editingCar: {
        accidents: newAccidentList
      },
    });
  }

  // Just force update - this.state.editingCar was manipulated by <Accident />.
  onChange3 = () => {
    this.forceUpdate();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>Car Name: {this.state.editingCar.name}</div>
        <Accident
          accidents={this.state.editingCar.accidents}
          onChange1={this.onChange1}
          onChange2={this.onChange2}
          onChange3={this.onChange3}
        />
     </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <DisplayCard car={ myCar } />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Also on JSFiddle if you want to play around: https://jsfiddle.net/jamis0n003/fbkn5xdy/4/

**EDIT:** The React JS docs suggest integrating with "other libraries", such as Backbone models, using forceUpdate:
https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html#using-backbone-models-in-react-components

Answer (score 2):

When state is stored in a parent component and a child component wants to manipulate that state, the parent should pass a callback function to the child's props. Then the child calls the callback to notify the parent to modify its own state. The child should **never** modify props since the change can have unintended consequences due to the way objects are referenced in JavaScript.

If you want to get really fancy, you can use Redux which stores "global" state in the top-most parent component. All child components issue (or dispatch) actions which notify the top-level parent to update its state which is then passed down again to all children components through their props.

Comment: Thats what I have setup in 3 different ways in the example code above. Do you think `onChange1` then is the best approach?

Comment: @jamis0n `handleButton1` and `handleButton2` look the same to me and both seem like the right way to solve this problem. 3 and 4 modify props, which is not the React way.

Comment: `handleButton2` calls `onChange2` in the parent, which incorrectly modifies `editingCar` in the parent.

`onChange1` is the only functional solution I have, but I'd like to know if theres a better way.

Comment: @jamis0n Yes, the one which calls `onChange1()` is better. Since you immediately call `setState()`, you don't need to worry about modifying the existing object from the current state. The change will propagate correctly on the next round of rendering.

Comment: Agreed - However I think calling `this.forceUpdate` is more meaningful to what is actually happening as opposed to `this.setState(prevState)`

Comment: @jamis0n I am not familiar with `forceUpdate()`, so I cannot comment on that.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the right way for the child to manipulate properties of the `Car` instance?

In general, rely on `setState()` to update state, which will reliably redraw the view, or if you mutate the data use `forceRedraw()` to ensure the view is redrawn with the latest data -- but using `setState()` is much preferred. In either case a child must notify a parent of a change using a callback like you have, but instead of having the child `Accident` actually change the data, make it a "dumb" component which notifies the parent of an intended change and the parent actually makes the change.

> I'd like to avoid a heavy handed solution like Flux to store this state.

You may want to look into [MobX](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx), which is popular alternative to Flux/Redux that is a bit easier to get into because it allows you to mutate objects very much in the way you are already doing.

Comment: In my example then, I believe the most correct way to update `editingCar` without causing side effects to it is:

`this.state.editingCar.accidents.push(newAccident);`
`this.forceUpdate();  // We manually modified state, so notify our state management module accordinly`

Comment: @jamis0n Yes, I'd say so. Keep in mind this approach could get hard to reason about if your project gets large, which is why Flux, Redux, and MobX exist.